# Novice question concerning stat function in C using minGW-W64

Tags: c

This is a very novice question. This code successfully prints the file name (including extension) of the first file in the folder and then pauses until the Windows OS says it's stopped working. It does not print the return value of `stat` in `rc` nor breaks. It just stops working.

I'm using minGW-W64.

Coudl you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void)
{
  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *ep;
  struct stat *info;
  int rc;

  dp = opendir ("./");

  if (dp != NULL)
    {
      while ( ep = readdir( dp ) )
        {
          if ( *(ep->d_name) == '.' ) continue;
          printf( "Name : %s\n", ep->d_name );
          if ( ( rc = stat( ep->d_name, info ) ) != 0 )
             {
               printf( "rc : %d\n", rc );
               break;
             }
          printf( "size : %d", info->st_mode );
        }
      printf( "Broke" );
      (void) closedir (dp);
    }
  else
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
  return 0;
}
```

---

Here is a version that works after fixing it according to the comments below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (void)
{
  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *ep;
  struct stat info;
  int rc;

  dp = opendir ("./SQLite3");

  if (dp != NULL)
    {
      while ( ep = readdir( dp ) )
        {
          printf( "Name : %s, ", ep->d_name );
          if ( *(ep->d_name) == '.' )
            { 
              printf(" non-useful file\n");
              continue;
            }
          if ( ( rc = stat( ep->d_name, &info ) ) != 0 )
             {
               printf( "rc : %d\n", rc );
               printf( "errno : %d, strerror : %s\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
               break;
             }
          printf( "mode : %d, size : %d\n", info.st_mode, info.st_size );
        }
      printf( "Broke" );
      (void) closedir (dp);
    }
  else
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct stat *info;` This is never initialized, yet it's passed to `stat`. Instead, you could use a local `struct stat info;` and call `stat( ep->d_name, &info )`.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. Sorry for being dense here but isn't `info` just a pointer that the `stat` function is going to populate with file information?

Comment: @dxiv That worked, thank you. But I don't yet understand why.

Comment: @gary, `stat()` doesn't populate the pointer, it populates the area of memory that the pointer points to. by saying `struct stat info`, you're "making that area", and by passing `&info`, you're passing a pointer to it.

Comment: @Gary `int *p;` defines `p` as a pointer-to-int variable, but it does not initialize it so `p` does not point to anything in particular. Using it as if it pointed to an int, for example `int n = *p;` or `*p = 10;` results in *undefined behavior* because `p` does not point to a valid `int`. To initialize `p` you can either point it to an existing `int` e.g. `int n = 10, *p = &n;`, or dynamically allocate an `int` e.g. `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));`. The same applies to `struct stat *info;` in your code.

Comment: @dxiv @mr.fixit Thank you both. I've been using C primarily to use SQLite and I guess I got my self confused by declarations such as `sqlite3_stmt *stmt` and passing `&stmt` in a `sqlite3_prepare_v2` function. I now suppose that SQLite code is allocating the memory "for me" and all I have to do is remember to free it by destroying the prep. statement. Thanks again.

Comment: @Gary `passing &stmt` As a side comment, the `&` in itself is a clue. C passes arguments by value, so in order for a function to modify an argument, it must receive its address i.e. a pointer to it.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. I think I get that. Then `&stmt` is the address of a pointer to a `sqlite3_stmt` data allocation, i.e. a pointer to a pointer. All that gets declared locally is space to hold the pointer, and the space for the `sqlite3_stmt` is allocated somewhere in the header file for `sqlite3.h`. I thought I understood that when working with SQLite but I really didn't.